# Как передать дополнительную переменную в функцию нажатия button?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как передать дополнительную переменную в функцию?

```
button.Click += Click_2;

void Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Например

```
void Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, string str)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Через замыкание:

```
button.Click += (o, e) => Click_2(o, e, "foo");
```

Или через тэг:

```
button.Tag = "foo";
button.Click += Click_2;

void Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var button = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var str = (string)button.Tag;
}
```

Конкретно для кнопок и клика есть возможность использовать команды:

```
button.CommandParameter = "foo";
button.Command = new DelegateCommand<string>(Click_2);

void Click_2(string str) {
}
```

Здесь я использую DelegateCommand из библиотеки Prism, но есть и альтернативы (например, RelayCommand из библиотеки MmvmLight).

Answer (score 3):

```
button.Tag = str;
button.Click += Click_2;

void Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```